# problem related to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have 1 NSString *abc = @"Hardik";
i have NSMutableArray *array;
now i had written [array addobject:abc];

then i'm printing,NSLog(@"array = %@", array);

but i'm getting NULL
why?
I have  declared NSMutableArray *array; in a.h file
i had set @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *array;
@synthesize array;

and i have synthesize it but getting value NULL
I'm not able to understand it?

Answer (score 4):

You also need to initialise your array:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

This is pretty fundamental stuff. Have you read the "[Learning Objective C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594)" yet?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you haven't actually allocated `array`. Generally, you would do this in your initializer. (Don't forget to add a `release` to your `dealloc` method, too.) `@synthesize` creates the getter and setter, but you still have to handle allocating/deallocating the object yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your NSMutableArray* array property may not have been initialised?

Can you post your class init method?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the synthesized accessor within a class itself, you must use `self`. If you don't, you access the attribute's address directly bypassing the accessor methods. You need:

```
NSString *abc = @"Hardik";
[self.array addobject:abc];
NSLog(@"array = %@", self.array);
```

The reason this is important is that the synthesized methods usually also initialize the property. The internals of the synthesize array method would look something like:

```
-(NSArray *) array{
    if (array!=nil) {
        return array;
    }
    array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    return array;
}
```

`self.propertyName` is really just shorthand for `[self propertyName]` and `self.propertyName=someValue` is just shorthand for `[self setPropertyName:someValue]`.

Until you call `self.array` at least once, ***the array property is not initialized***.

However, just to confuse things, once you have called `self.array` once it is initialized so you can just call `array` directly. So...

```
[self.array addObject:abc];
NSLog(@"array = %@", array);
```

...works while the converse would return just an empty array.

So the rules are:

1. Within a class implementation
   (including subclasses), calling just
   `propertyName` gives you the address
   of the property but does not call
   the getter/setter accessor methods.
2. Within a class implementation
   (including subclasses), using
   `self.propertyName` calls the
   getter/setter accessor methods but
   does not access attribute directly.
3. From outside the class
   implementation e.g.
   `myClass.propertyName` calls the
   getter/setter accessor methods.